# How to update a temporary table with a value from a select statement?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have created a temporary table to hold some values like this:

```
CREATE TABLE #TempCount (PendingOrders INT, OpenOrders INT, ClosedOrders INT);
```

I want to update the columns with a value from a `SELECT` statement as such:

```
UPDATE #TempCount
    SET PendingOrders = 
    (
    SELECT
    COUNT(OrderID) AS 'PendingOrders'
    FROM
    dbo.Products
    WHERE
    OrderStatus = 1
    )
```

However nothing seems to get updated. I expected `PendingOrders` to show a number but it doesn't get anything entered in. The column is empty. The same applies to the other columns - nothing gets updated.

How could I solve this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need a row in order to update it. Do one "initializing" INSERT first:

```
INSERT INTO #TempCount VALUES(0, 0, 0)
```

Comment: Could I initialise with a NULL value at all?

Comment: Why not just change the update to an insert? Seems a lot simpler than inserting a row with default values and then updating them.

Comment: @SeanLange - what does that have to do with the OP? If the request is for a single row, updated when needed, an insert is wrong

Comment: From the code the OP posted it would seem an insert right after creating the table would make more sense. Hard to know for sure since we don't know the whole process.

Answer (score 2):

Seems to me like you need an insert statement first to generate the row.

```
INSERT #TempCount (PendingOrders)
SELECT COUNT(OrderID) AS 'PendingOrders'
FROM dbo.Products
WHERE OrderStatus = 1
```

Comment: This will insert a new row for each of the different types of orders.  I only need 1 row, with a value in for each column.

Comment: Thanks for the downvote. Not a lot of detail provided and I took a shot in the dark.

Comment: I tried to undo the downvote but it didn't let me. I _am_ thankful for your help.

Answer (score 2):

If you just want to hold single values then consider variables

```
declare @PendingOrders int
set @PendingOrders = ( SELECT COUNT(OrderID) 
                       FROM dbo.Products 
                       WHERE OrderStatus = 1 )  


select @PendingOrders, @OpenOrders, @ClosedOrders
```

Comment: I need to combine all my results into one resultset to return back to the web application hence the temp table.

Comment: Uh, select atPendingOrders, atOpenOrders, atClosedOrders

Comment: Why is this better than using a temp table?

Comment: I said consider.  Setter does not have the overhead of a table.   With a setter it is clear you are dealing with single value.   Syntax is cleaner.

Answer (score 1):

Use this syntax:

```
UPDATE t
  SET t.xxx=p.xxx
    FROM #TempCount t, Products p
      WHERE ......
```

Subselect is not always necessary.